# Tension and Shear on L-Bracket Offset From Wall

Tags: fasteners, shear, tension

I’m planning to mount a mantle on a brick fireplace wall using two iron L-brackets that are 5” wide and 1/4” thick. Each bracket has four 5/16” mounting holes…two at the top and two at the bottom. The bracket is 5-3/4” deep including the lip at the front and the back portion of the bracket is 8-7/16” tall. The brackets weigh about 7-1/2 lbs each.

[image]
[image]

The mantle weighs about 50 lbs and is about 3-1/2” x 5-1/2”. So once mounted, the COG of the mantle will be about 2-3/4” from the wall. The distance from the center of the top mounting holes to the bottom of the bracket is 7-3/16”.

Without accounting for the weight of the brackets themselves, the tension load from the mantle on the top four screws would be…

Force = (2.75 / 7.1875) * 50

Force = 19.13 lbs

1. Am I calculating this correctly?
2. How do you account for the weight of the brackets?

All that said, my primary issue is that the brick is not plumb and is somewhat uneven. I would like to use some steel shims/washers/spacers between the bracket and the brick wall in order to make the brackets plumb. Spacers would likely be about 1/8” or 3/16”. I assume that adding spacers to the bottom mounting holes would have a different impact than adding spacers to the top holes since my understanding is that only the top screws/anchors are under tension and the bottom fasteners are only under shear.

3. How would adding these spacers affect the tension and shear loads on the screws and anchors? What if I’m only adding spacers to one or two of the corners while the other corners maintain direct contact with the brick? What if spacers were added to all four corners, and perhaps to a thickness that removed all direct contact between the bracket and the brick where the bracket was completely offset from the brick wall? How significantly would these scenarios affect the tension and shear loads on the screws and anchors?

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are correct but give the total raw tension on four screws. If you divide it by 4 you get the tensile force on each screw.
As for adding washers as spacers to make the wall plumb, it is okay as long as you keep them as fit and as tight as possible. And preferably use lock washers. Avoid using multiple washers in the same anchor. The idea is the washer becomes an integral part of the wall, not a fastener.

Are you not ever going to hang something on the mantel or put a picture frame on it?

I would add 100lbs to the self-weight, as a safety factor to cover the effect of the brackets and possible future objects placed on the mantel.
The stresses on the top screws will be tension and shear and shear alone on the bottom.

In these kinds of applications, chances are the distribution of the loads is uneven e.g. possibly the screws on the top position don't share the load evenly. You want to tighten the screws gradually going from one to the other in small steps.

Comment: Thank you sir. I forgot to mention that the fireplace and mantle are quite wide, 8’8”. I do realize that my calculation was for the total tension load and that it would be spread across the top four screws, but perhaps unevenly. A large picture will hang above the mantle at nearly the full width, so very little will be set on the mantle. However, point well taken on the safety factor. I think I understand your point about using lock washers. So adding washers doesn’t significantly affect the tension and shear calcs? How thick of a washer/shim can I use before it would be an issue?

Comment: I am just guessing a 1/4-inch screw or anchor could cantilever 3/16 of an inch if the washer slides and loses the grip for some reason. you should use a substantial epoxy anchor and check the integrity of the wall beforehand.

Comment: Regarding the anchor, I’ve been debating the best thing to use. The brick is the three hole type. So  options that I initially considered such as sleeve anchors likely won’t work. There’s 1” of actual brick from the face to the interior core holes. Here’s a post with details and pics of what I’m working with…
https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/284368/mantle-brackets-on-brick-fireplace-wall
Could you take a quick look? I’m actually looking at Toggler Alligator anchors since they are for solid masonry but can handle cavities. It’s a polypropylene anchor but seems quite substantial.

Comment: Brick and mortar appear very solid with no apparent cracking or issues. I’m considering the AF8 Toggler Alligator anchor… https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/BISS/Guides/TOGGLER/TOGGLER_ALLIGATOR_TechnicalBulletin.pdf
It’s a 5/16” anchor and I’m planning to use a 1/4” stainless steel lag or SMS. I’m sure I’m over-thinking all this considering the fairly small amount of weight…especially when spread across multiple anchors/screws.

Comment: @jdchess, when a bit of extra strength can be provided with just a little extra expense, no hesitation is needed. One reason to be cautious is the long thick mantel could warp, twist, and creep over time inducing torqe and twist to the anchors. Good luck.